# ChartJS disable gridlines outside chart area

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to hide the gridlines drawn outside the chart area, so basically like the option below, but for outside the chart area

```
gridLines: {
  drawOnChartArea: false,
},
```

[image: exmpl]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably you are looking to disable the tick lines which can be achieved via the `drawTicks` property:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('canvas'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'series1',
      data: [1, 2, 4]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          drawTicks: false
        },
        ticks: {
          padding: 10
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          drawTicks: false
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          padding: 10
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas">
```

```
gridLines:
  drawTicks: false;
}
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration) for further information.