# Making sure gridlines do not cross y-axis with ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

As seen on image below, how can i stop the gridlines from crossing the y-axis? I think it looks cleaner that way.

[image]

Comment: this should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54179607/chartjs-disable-gridlines-outside-chart-area

Answer (score 1):

Set `options.scales.yAxes[0].gridLines.drawTicks` to false and and some padding in `gridLines.ticks.padding`:

```js
{
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Users',
      data: [50, 60, 70, 180]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          drawTicks: false,
        },
        ticks: {
          padding: 8,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

[image: bar chart without ticks]